# What is the meaning of 'plain' dangerous?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, early-modern-english, cinema

I watched [a movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1454029/) and found a line saying:

> It's just plain dangerous. They carry different diseases than we do.

I am wondering what the meaning of 'plain' dangerous is?

I checked [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plain) but still don't understand which meaning fits the context.

Could you explain the meaning of the 'plain'?

Some snippets of dialogue (including the line question) may be found on this [WordPress blog][3].

Comment: Just plain obvious.

Comment: no ifs ands or buts

Comment: I think it may have come from _It is plainly dangerous_ and is an idiomatic contraction.

Comment: Not so much a contraction as just an (old-fashioned) flat adverb.

Comment: It's an "intensifier".

Comment: So, is it called a 'flat intensifier' ?

Answer (score 4):

> You can use plain before an adjective in order to emphasize it: The
>   food was just plain terrible. Plain is also used before a noun: Is it
>   love of publicity or plain stupidity on her part?

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plain)

Answer (score 3):

The following definition from Dictionary.com may fit:

[Plain](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plain)

> 4) downright; sheer; utter; self-evident:
>
> - *plain folly; plain stupidity.*

Comment: +1, though technically that's an adjective definition (whereas the OP's example is using it as an adverb).